# EventEmitter emit is not working in angular 4

Tags: angular, emit

here is my code below :

**search.component.html**

```
<button (click)="addMe()">Click</button>
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Directive, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'search-component',
   templateUrl: './search.component.html'
})

export class SearchComponent {
   @Output() userUpdated = new EventEmitter();

   addMe() {
       this.userUpdated.emit('my data to emit');
   }
}
```

**profile.component.html**

```
<search-component (userUpdated)="handleUserUpdated($event)"></search-component>
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
handleUserUpdated(e) {
   console.log('e', e);
}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: What does the module look like?

Comment: Are you sure `SearchComponent` is instantiated? Did you add it to `declarations:[]`

Comment: `new EventEmitter<any>();`

Comment: Emitter type does not matter guys...

Comment: @Carsten It does not matter but it have to be casted right?

Comment: There is no error but handleUserUpdated method is not called log @RahulSingh

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find the cause?

Comment: I didn't catch anything wrong.
But if you ever tried `myEmitter.emit(data)` in the constructor it can be an issue I don't know why. I came here because I was calling  `.emit()` in the constructor and after I call it in `ngAfterViewInit()` method which it's coming from `AfterViewInit` interface emit method woked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should need to declare a type. Use `@Output() userUpdated = new EventEmitter<string>();` if you want it to be a string or `@Output() userUpdated = new EventEmitter<any>();` if it can be any type.

Also, you need to change your console log, try swapping to `console.log("e-" + e)`

Comment: This is exactly what I would have suggested, not sure why you got down voted.

Comment: Its because you apparently dont need to declare a type for the EventEmitter, even though intellisense will complain if you dont

Comment: what you mean is not the typing itself, it is the correct EventEmitter initialization using the assignment and the type. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: @Nadine can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: check the Angular docu for that. It needs to be initialized. The answer has the type declaration in the wrong place: @Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

Comment: @Nadine this was originally for angular 4 iirc, and as the docs will not be for v7/8, thing will probabably have changed

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter those are the up to date docs. But your IDE should provide a syntax check and inform you anyways... The key fact is that an EventEmitter needs to be initialized.

Comment: @Nadine that is exactly what this answer does, or atleast did at the time of writing